# Custom qt spinbox for auto rotating values after reaching the limits

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qspinbox

I want my Qt Spin-box to rotate the values when an user reaches the two ends of the value range.

e.g. let my range is 0 to 10 with increments of 2. After clicking the increment button of the spin-box when the value is already 10, usually nothing happens. But I want it to rotate the value back to the first value which will be 0.

Which member function shall I have to override to catch the event of the user- attempt to change the value in QSpinBox class?

```
class MyCustomSpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    // override this function to get the effect of rotating
    void override_func()
    {
    // code to rotate the value 
    }
};
```

Or, is it that there already exists some property of it such that I can just set in qt-creator (may-be) to get the same rotating values effect?

Thanks.

Comment: exactly, at the two ends, it can continue apparently never-endingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just enable wrapping .

For example.

```
QSpinBox *spinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
spinBox->setRange(0, 100);
spinBox->setWrapping(true);
spinBox->setValue(100);
spinBox->stepBy(1);
// value is 0
```

[image]